# angular 2 table row hover for showing buttons on hovered row

Tags: angular, html-table, row

I'm stuck on getting on-mouseover event to show hidden edit button on row.  Using this method, it will show all edit buttons on each row.  I had this working in AngularJs 1x just because the ng-mouseenter set a the scope inside of each tr element.  However, this is not the case with angular 2.

```
<table>
   <tr *ngFor="let ob of objects" on-mouseover="rowHovered=true" on-mouseleave="rowHovered=false">
     <td>{{ob.name}}</td>
     <td>
        <button *ngIf="rowHovered==true">edit</button>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try storing the hovered index:

```
<table on-mouseleave="hoveredIndex=null">
   <tr *ngFor="let ob of objects; let index=index" on-mouseover="hoveredIndex=index">
     <td>{{ob.name}}</td>
     <td>
        <button *ngIf="index==hoveredIndex">edit</button>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm also not sure about the `on-mouseover` syntax.  consider using angular event binding instead `(mouseover)='hoveredIndex = index'`

Comment: Thank you for a quick response.  for this case, I like the on-mouseover method since all the logic is right there on the same page and there is no need to to go dig into TS file.

Comment: the event binding syntax doesnt require typescript; it can evaluate expressions the same way